# Confusion regarding pseudo force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames, acceleration, inertial-frames

I have been taught that a pseudo force is a force that appears to act on a mass whose motion is being described using a non-inertial frame of reference

I have also been taught that pseudo force = - (mass of object × acceleration of non-inertial frame).

But what if both the object and the observer's frame are accelerating at same rates?
Shouldn't the observer feel that the net force on the object is 0? If so, then pseudo force=0.
But if we apply the formula I have been taught then pseudo force ≠0
Where am I going wrong?

I also have doubts regarding what exactly a pseudo force is. From what I have read, pseudo force is the force an object feels due to its inertia. But in the example given above, I can't really figure out where inertia comes in the picture.

Comment: Why should the observer not measure  or see the calculated force? Standing on a rotating platform  all objects including you as observer feel the "centrifugal" force, if you move you and moving objects  feel the Coriolis force.Just by observing these forces you can know that you are not in a inertial system.

Comment: @trula I have edited my question a bit. My understanding of pseudo forces is a bit shaky. Could you please first clarify the doubt I have added at the end ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, they accelerate to the same rate relative to what? Let say they both have acceleration *a* relative to an inertial frame. So in the inertial frame there must be a (real, not pseudo) force accelerating the object, $F_r=ma$. In the non-inertial frame the same force acts but you also have the inertial force $F_i=-ma$. So form the point of view of the noninertial frame the net force is zero and there is no acceleration.

Comment: Does this mean that pseudo forces and inertial are two different things since the inertial force here is -ma and the pseudo force observed by the non inertial frame is 0

Comment: It's not the pseudoforce but the net force which is observed to be zero in the non-inertial frame. Net force means the sum of all forces. In the non-inertial frame you have the real force and the pseudo-force acting in opposite directions so the NET force is zero and there is no acceleration. In the inertial frame there is only the real force so the net force is not zero and there is an acceleration. There is no inertial (or pseudo) force in the inertial frame.  The frame being called "inertial" has nothing to do with "inertial force". Inertial forces are introduced in the non-inertial frames.

Comment: Ohk, now I know where I was going wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To (badly) quote Einstein, pseudo-forces are an ugly way to express the fact that the chosen frame isn't inertial.

Say you're in a bus. As long as the bus goes in a straight line with constant velocity, its frame is inertial. Roughly speaking, if you close your eyes you can't tell whether it's moving or not.

Then the bus slows down. Choosing a frame is a way to choose the point of view of an observer, so:

- From your point of view (=in the non-inertial frame), you feel like a force is pulling you forward. However, notice that it'd be a force with no source (no physical system is applying a force to pull you).
- For an observer standing on the side of the road (=inertial frame), you're simply satisfying Newton's first law, as you keep moving forward with your previous velocity while the bus slows down.

The very fact that pseudo-forces may exist or not, depending on the frame, means that they aren't forces at all. But it's convenient to treat them as such, at least in classical mechanics.

As for your example of an object accelerating at the same rate as the chosen frame, the study of such a case isn't straightforward in general. If the non-inertial frame has a linear motion with relation to an inertial frame, then it's simple: the object has no acceleration in the non-inertial frame, so it's moving at constant velocity in it.

The formula you mentioned, pseudo force = - (mass of object × acceleration of non-inertial frame), isn't correct in the general case. Let $R$ be an inertial frame and $R'$ a non-inertial frame.

In the general case, pseudo-forces are split in two terms:

- $\vec{F}_e$ : a part that doesn't depend on the object's velocity in $R'$. Some authors split this term into two forces called Euler force and centrifugal force.
- $\vec{F}_c$ : a part that does (Coriolis force).

$\vec{F}_e$ has a rather complicated expression in the general case. But if $R'$ has a linear motion in respect to $R$, then:

$$\vec{F}_e=-m\vec{a}(O'/R)$$

with $O'$ the origin of frame $R'$. In this simple case, then what you said is correct.

Comment: So the pseudo force observed by the other block will be 0. But like one answer says below, the inertial force will be -ma. Does that mean that pseudo forces and inertial forces are two different things altogether?

Comment: No, they're the same thing. The fact that they differ from a frame to the other (= from one observer to the other) is the very point. They aren't real forces, just inertial effects written as forces.

Comment: Ohk, I get it now. Thanks a lot!